# Pyinstaller does not work on an image show python application? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, linux, exe, pyinstaller

I have this imsple code for testing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cv2
import sys
import os


if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    app_path = sys.MEIPASS
else:
    app_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))



img = cv2.imread('sammy_noise.jpg')
cv2.imshow('It works?', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Just an image show.

And I want to make this script work with double click.
I installed pypinstaller. And I ran this in the terminal:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data="sammy_noise.jpg:." test.py
```

The build is successfully but when I try to double click the exe file in the dist folder nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this way:

`pyinstaller --onefile --add-data=sammy_noise.jpg;. test.py`